disaper Power Mode setting with TLP
i uninstalled tlp in my laptop with ubuntu 2204 and reboot,later that disappear the battery mode where i could select between: Super Battery,hight Performance  or Standar how can i fix that ? how can recovery that fuction?

i solved
sudo apt -y install power-profiles-daemon

